# Using the system setup icon

Tags: c++, icons, wtl

I'm developing a windows application in C++. I use wtl. One of the application window's title bar should display a system setup icon as it is in a typical setup program. Could you please share a way how can a load a system setup icon into my application if OS provides it?

Comment: Answer this first. Why has Stack Overflow provided transparent click able water marked tick that goes green with mouse over next to replies? if you can see one here check your previous questions.

Answer (score 2):

- Add a resource file into your project.
- Add icon resource into your project.
- Build them together.